# loop function with different number of argument python

Tags: python, loops, parameter-passing, sympy

I am trying to loop over a function that allows different number of arguments
(sympy.Polygon)

every iteration the code must set a different polygon, so it could be 3,4 o n number of vertices:

```
sympy.Polygon(a1,a2,a3)
sympy.Polygon(b1,b2,b3,b4,b5)
```

how can I set this task ?

Comment: It's probably worth reviewing [Unpacking Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) and the `*` operator when used as `*<iterable>`.

Comment: I agree with jedwards, you could do something like `simpy.Polygon(*[your_args])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
import sympy

points = [(0,0),(0,1), (1,1), (1,2)]
sympy.Polygon(*points)
```

Using * you can send any number of arguments to sympy.Polygon.

Best

Answer (score 1):

For nameless arguments as you want you could use `*argv` as in this way

```
def Ploygon(*argv):  
    for arg in argv:  
        print (arg)
```

If you need named variables look into `**kwargs`

Answer (score 1):

```
def some_function(*args):
    print("New function call---")
    for arg in args:
        print("arg =>",arg)


some_function("arg1","arg2","arg3")
some_function("arg1","arg2")
some_function("arg1","arg2","arg3", "arg4")
```

You can achieve that as above example.

**Output:**

```
New function call---
arg => arg1
arg => arg2
arg => arg3
New function call---
arg => arg1
arg => arg2
New function call---
arg => arg1
arg => arg2
arg => arg3
arg => arg4
```